# Basic authentication for WCF OData service - turn off logon rederection

Tags: c#, authentication, redirect, basic-authentication

I have implemented a secure WCF Odata service as instructed on msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192997.aspx

When i go to the Service on:
http://localhost/MyOData/ODataService.svc/Orders

the authentication get's in the pipeline correctly and when i authenticate myself it is done correctly.

But then i get redirected to:

http://localhost/MyOData/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMyOData%2fODataService.svc%2fOrders

This does not return any data. Since i'm consuming this service from another tool it does not work. After authentication i should just go back to this URL:
http://localhost/MyOData/ODataService.svc/Orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set

```
response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

on my response, redirection was disabled